# php not inserting json data to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

this is my first question; and I am a NOVICE trying to learn. My json looks like this:

```
    array(1) {["usersJSON"]=>string(143) 
"[{"userId":"1","userName":"Emilio"},{"userId":"2","userName":"Andre"},
{"userId":"3","userName":"Kristina"},
{"userId":"4","userName":"Damaris"}]"}string(143) 
"[{"userId":"1","userName":"Emilio"},{"userId":"2","userName":"Andre"},
{"userId":"3","userName":"Kristina"},{"userId":"4","userName":"Damaris"}]"
[{"id":"1","status":"no"},{"id":"2","status":"no"},{"id":"3","status":"no"},
{"id":"4","status":"no"}]
```

and my php page looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions class 
$db = new DB_Functions(); 
var_dump($_POST);
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"];
error_log (var_dump($json));
//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json); 
}
//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]->userId,$data[$i]->userName);
//Based on inserttion, create JSON response
if($res){
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
    $b["status"] = 'yes';
    array_push($a,$b);
}else{
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
    $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
}
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

I have done so much debuggin I am going buggy. I can see in the logs where the php page is accessing my database and attempting to insert data; but this is what the server log says:
    70.193.209.170 - - [14/May/2015:06:37:45 -0500] "POST /webservice2/insertuser.php HTTP/1.0" 200 393 "-" "-"

I've even gone as far as hiring someone from outsource.com. Long story short; I ended up right where I started and I'm down $200 bucks. He basically came back and said "the problem is in your php page..." and even though my ad explicitly said "I need PHP help" the guy then says he doesn't know PHP.

Anyhow; looking for some guidance and any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and input.

Comment: you can add me skype i am online   sinan.artun

Answer (score 0):

You have decoded the json so it converts back to a normal array and you are trying to use an associative array as an object. Access it in the normal manner that you normally do to access 2 dimensional associative array.

Please use the below code:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions class 
$db = new DB_Functions(); 
var_dump($_POST);
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"];
error_log (var_dump($json));
//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json); 
}
//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]['userId'],$data[$i]['userName']);
//Based on inserttion, create JSON response
if($res){
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]['userId'];
    $b["status"] = 'yes';
    array_push($a,$b);
}else{
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]['userId'];
    $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
}
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);
```

?>

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Well, some progress made! Thanks so much to both who have answered. I'm still in the same boat; but at least I am getting this message:"Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!"

Comment: @dgore, may i know if you'd like to get more help on this if you are stuck anywhere.

Comment: well....I think I am making more progress. after looking at my logcat (btw I am using eclipse luna) the data string being sent does not match what the outsource guy said.  the logcat appears like this:

Comment: 05-15 02:10:22.635: I/System.out(9226):   ["usersJSON"]=>
05-15 02:10:22.635: I/System.out(9226):   string(67) "[{"userName":"dede","userId":"1"},{"userName":"gggg","userId":"2"}]"
05-15 02:10:22.635: I/System.out(9226): }
05-15 02:10:22.635: I/System.out(9226): string(67) "[{"userName":"dede","userId":"1"},{"userName":"gggg","userId":"2"}]"
05-15 02:10:22.635: I/System.out(9226): [{"id":"1","status":"no"},{"id":"2","status":"no"}]

Comment: That would be great @Sourabh